# Can we say "رضی الله عنه " after Khalid bin Al-Walid?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

There is a tradition In [Sahih Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/368), Book 64, Hadith 368 in which The Prophet (pbuh) stated clearly his low opinion on what Khalid had committed:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) sent Khalid bin Al-Walid to the tribe of Jadhima and
> Khalid invited them to Islam but they could not express themselves by
> saying, "Aslamna (i.e. we have embraced Islam)," but they started
> saying "Saba'na! Saba'na (i.e. we have come out of one religion to
> another)." Khalid kept on killing (some of) them and taking (some of)
> them as captives and gave every one of us his Captive. When there came
> the day then Khalid ordered that each man (i.e. Muslim soldier) should
> kill his captive, I said, "By Allah, I will not kill my captive, and
> none of my companions will kill his captive." When we reached the
> Prophet, we mentioned to him the whole story. On that, the Prophet (ﷺ)
> raised both his hands and said twice, "O Allah! I am free from what
> Khalid has done."

knowing that The Prophet (pbuh) did not please with him, can we say that Allah was pleased with Khalid bin Al-Walid by mentioning "**رضی الله عنه**" after his name?

Comment: Why not Prophet(Peace be upon him) has not told anything that he is not from my companion.He never told that Khalid radiallahu-anha is now did a greate mistake and not from my companions. so why should we exclude him.

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between sin and mistake, Mohammad (pbuh) himself didn't know whether Khalid bin Walid committed a sin or mistake, so he left it with Allah (swt) who is the all knower.

Considering Khalid bin Walid's massive role in defense of Islam, it is unwise to make assumption, that's exactly why Mohammad (pbuh) did not make any assumptions about him.

Let's not forget the label Prophet Mohammad (pbuh) gave him:

> "The Sword Of Allah"

If he is regarded as the sword of Allah by Prophet Mohammad (pbuh), how can anyone dispute his status and reject him the "honorific/du`a "May Allah be pleased with him.""? (Ansari)

Answer (score 1):

The status of a person is decided by the entirety of their actions, not one single action. The incident of Jadhima happened when Khalid was a brand new Muslim. After that he repented and went on to become an exemplary Muslim. This is why he is still accorded the honorific/du`a "May Allah be pleased with him."

Answer (score 1):

This is hadith but it doesn't mean that khalid bin walid (Allah be pleased with him) is a bad person or something.What he did was something very wrong, but he was still a great sahaba. We shouldn't disrespect him. After all he was dubbed the sword of Allah by the prophet. May Allah forgive him for this sin. He was one of the best warriors of Islam. Watch this: [www.youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8jTe7rKvH0)

Answer (score -2):

Assalamualaikum,

All As'hab an Nabi (Companions of the Prophet) Sallallahu alaihiwa sallam as attributed with Radhiallahu Anhu and one deed of his life that Prophet SAW didn't like, as per my opinion, in no way makes his deprived of the Radhiallahu Anhu attribution.

Allahu A'alam

Answer (score -2):

Khalid Bin Waleed (May Allah, the Almighty be pleased with him) was one person who was chosen as wrath of Allah, the Almighty for those Muslims who disobeyed the orders of the Prophet (Salat o Salam) in Ohad. Allah Hakeem and Aleem blessed Khalid Bin Waleed (R,A) with hidayat and he came to Madina and had presented himself to the Prophet (Salat o Salam) long before the Conquest of Mecca. One should be rest assure that during the life of the Prophet (Salaat o Salam) if any such incident had taken place, Allah, Hakeem & Aleem had revealed the verses in that regard. We know how much obedient a soldier of Islam was Khalid Bin Waleed (R,A) that in one occasion he was removed from the command by Umar Bin Khitab (R.A) and he fought the battle as a plain soldier. but Muslims could not win the battle, subsequently the new commander in Chief voluntarily gave the command to Khalid Bin Waleed (R.A) who defeated the enemy. The help of Allah, Al Qawwee al Ghafoor was always with Khalid Bin Waleed (R.A). He defeated the enemies of Allah, the Greatest in every nook and corner. As Muslims we should refrain ourselves from such Hadees which only create confusion. To get an assured success in Aakharat we should restrict ourselves to Quran, al Hakeem, which covers all the details we need to know. Its only Allah, Ghafoor ur Rahim Who blesses people with guidance.

Answer (score -4):

Well the Qur'an says it explicitly:

> **[Qur'an (5:32)](http://quran.com/5/32)**
>
> …the killing of a person for reasons other than legal retaliation or
> for stopping corruption in the land is as great a sin as murdering all
> of mankind. However, to save a life would be as great a virtue as to
> save all of mankind.…

For those who say that "this was only one mistake" or "it was a small mistake," they do not understand the depth of the sin Khalid ibn Waleed did:  He killed many innocent people, **hence he gained the Sin and Azaab of killing Humanity many times over.**

And also please notice, The Prophet is the Mercy for all of Allah's Creation. Yet when the Prophet heard about this action done by Waleed the prophet didn't say, "May Allah forgive him," rather he said "Oh Allah, I am free from this action."

And for those who say that Waleed went onto become an exemplary Muslim, Wikipedia says otherwise:

> Abu Qatada Ansari, a companion of Muhammad, who accompanied Khalid
> from Medina was so shocked at Malik's murder by Khalid that he
> immediately returned to Medina, and told Abu Bakr that he refused to
> serve under a commander who had killed a Muslim. The death of Malik
> and Khalid's taking of his wife Layla created controversy. Some
> officers of his army—including Abu Qatadah—believed that Khalid killed
> Malik to take his wife. After the pressure exerted by Umar—Khalid's
> cousin and one of Caliph Abu Bakr's main advisors—Abu Bakr called
> Khalid back to Medina to explain himself. Although Khalid had declared
> Malik an apostate, in Medina, ‘Umar told Khalid: “You enemy of Allâh!
> You killed a Muslim man and thereafter took his wife. By Allâh, I will
> stone you".

Comment: The verse Clearly says that The killing of a person for reasons other than legal retaliation or for stopping corruption in the land. His decision may be wrong but he has done this with a reason he is fighting with them for islam not for his personnal.

Comment: Also for your second comment... tell me how does a man become apostate by taking back, or not paying the Zakaat?? I always thought one becomes apostate by rejecting Prophet Muhammad and Allah.... What is your definition of apostate?

Comment: P.S .. when I quoted the Qur'anic ayat... I was trying to tell .. that there is no compulsion in religion... yet Waleed, forced people to accept Islam by Killing them.

Comment: Allah and His messenger knows best.I am not defending and who I am to defend. And why should I not keep Khalid radiallahu anha. As prophet sallalahu alahi wassalam knows what khalid bin walid raziallahu anha did. He never told that he did sin he did mistake he just put the decision on allah saying **Oh Allah, I am free from this action" .** and there is no Quranic verse after that which states that khalid raziallahu-anha did a greate mistake etc...

Comment: In context, 5:32 is clearly referring to the laws of Bani Isra'eel.  If you're going to apply that rule to this situation, you need to expand on your presented logic.  And even then, given that Allah can explicitly forgive any sins short of shirk, you would still need to explain why having committed such a sin would still be unforgiveable.

Comment: @ali786 .I think it is clear, when the prophet says that I am free from this action, he is referring to a mistake and/or sin.  Why else would the prophet say such a thing? The way you are explaining it makes it seem the prophet didnt know if waleed did a sin or not.But remember, prophet is supposed to be the benchmark of our actions.If the prophet didn't know (according to what I understand from ur explanation) what waleed did was sin or not.then are u not lowering the status of the prophet from his position of being the benchmark, the exemplar for all good actions? And staying away from bad

Comment: @goldPseudo .. Please elaborate what you mean by "referring to the laws of Bani Isra'eel". From what I understand there are 2 verses in the Qur'an. The Muhkamaat(Decisive) and the Mutashabihaat(allegorical). 5:32 in my understanding is a muhkaam verse. Which applies to all times and all people. Killing of one innocent man amounts to killing of all humanity. Please explain how this verse only applies to the Bani Isra'eel.

Comment: @Ali How is it not obvious from reading the ayah?  The first part of the sentence that you didn't bother to quote entirely clearly states "We made it a law for the children of Israel that the killing of..."

Comment: @goldPseudo .. Sorry let me reiterate. Can you please explain, how this rule only and only applies to Bani Isra'eel ?

Comment: @Ali don't get wrong meaning what I am telling is prophet Muhammed Peace be upon him knows every thing but still he didn't told that He did a great sin and He is not among my companion. If he ever told like that Please put a reference for that not your own opinions.And the same  are u not lowering the status of the companion of the prophet from his position.

Comment: This post does have some factual truth, but it seems to be more of a jab at khalid's(RA) character than it is an answer. It would be better if you had tried to contextualise the character of Khalid with the good he did for the muslims and Islam too, since that on its own is could be a basis for calling him a companion.

Comment: @Andre  when did Al walid convert ANYONE to islam?